# Обработка POST запроса на Koa.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa.js

Почему на запрос cts.request.body я ничего не получаю?

JS

```
 fetch("/", {
        method: "POST",
        body:  {data: "data"},
    })
    .then(response => {
        return response.json()
    })
```

koa.js

```
 const Router = require('koa-router');
 const router = new Router({});

  router.post('/', async function(ctx) {
    const user = await ctx.request.body;
   console.log(user);
  });
```

Comment: `ctx.request.body` это не `Promise` + сеттите нужные хедеры как в [этом примере](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29823632/10123947)

Comment: @overthesanity, await убрал. Тестирую через postMan- все равно не получаю ответ

Comment: вы используете `koa-bodyparser`?

Comment: @overthesanity, нет

Comment: а где в документации написано за `ctx.request.body`? [ctx.request.body](https://github.com/koajs/bodyparser#usage)

Comment: @overthesanity, ну я дурак :D ! Спасибо